# Reputation from subsites for Overflow careers

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I want to start using SO Careers, however the majority of my reputation is in the SharePoint StackExchange subsite. When a recruiter sees a profile in Careers he only sees the Stack Overflow reputation, right? Is there a way of aggregating the reputation, or at least some mechanism to make subsites reputation useful for Carrers?

N.B.:Not sure if Meta is the correct place for this discussion, but let me know in the comments if it isn't please and I'll move it.

Comment: @CodyGray Your reply works for me :) Put it as an answer (if the mechanism is not obvious please include a screenshot to help me and others) and I'll mark it as accepted . Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Careers profile can display reputation earned on other sites, as well as Stack Overflow.
In fact, which sites are displayed is completely customizable.

To configure it, go to your CV. Under the "Stack Exchange" heading, you'll see "Accounts" as the first item. Hover over it, and click the blue "edit" button. You'll get a list of all the sites you have accounts on on the Stack Exchange network. Check the ones you want to be displayed. Finally, click the blue "Save" button at the bottom.

[image]